# I want to encrypt my SSD, should I still use TrueCrypt or Is there a better open source alternative?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, privacy, disk-encryption, truecrypt

Before anything I have say that I have no experience with cryptography, at all. Anyway, I have a laptop with Windows 10 and an SSD. I don't want to use BitLocker since I don't trust Microsoft in this matter.

I've read that TrueCrypt 7.1a is still safe despite being abandoned by the developers, but everything I've read was from about 2 years ago, so I don't know if it still is a good alternative.

I'm also considering VeraCrypt, but some people say isn't safe because it wasn't audited yet. So, what are some good and reliable open source alternatives to encrypt my system?

Comment: @RoraΖ That's still from a year ago, I think that's a lot of time in this case.

Comment: If your drive and BIOS support FDE (full disk encryption) that is the best option - performance is much better than software encryption

Comment: For what it's worth, there's basically no point in encrypting anything while running an OS you don't trust. If you think Microsoft has backdoored BitLocker (and, having briefly worked on it for Win7, at least at that time I saw no evidence of this), why do you think they won't also keylog (or otherwise extract) your TrueCrypt (or whatever) passphrase / key? Or simply wait for you to decrypt the volume, then mirror off the bits?

Answer (score 1):

TrueCrypt is still very reliable encryption software. Of course, the key that set is, well the "key" (pun somewhat intended). There are multiple reliable encryption tools for your operating system, most people here won't list them off because of course they may be the creators of said software. I can tell you from personal experience that TrueCrypt, Bitlocker and VeraCrypt are very reliable encryption softwares. Read blogs regarding the matter, and make the decision based upon that. Of course, ever crappy encryption software can be a pain to crack if your encryption key is very secure.

Best of luck in your search, and if you have questions about others, add a comment I will gladly give my 2 cents, as I'm sure others on here will as well.